# how Task.run works

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
     try
     {
         RunPrePopulation();
         List<TimeSlotInfo2> timeslotsAsync = GetTimeSlotsCompleteWebAPI(currentDate, timeslotLength, false, 30, false, -1, "", maUser);
         TimeslotsAllocation(timeslot, timeslotLength, currentDate, timeslotsAsync);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\dev\\logs\\Threaderrors.txt", true);
         file.Write(ex.StackTrace);
     }
});
```

I'm working on a custom schedule algorithum to help schedule interviews. This method is called via a jquery ajax call which when completed is supposed to redriect the user to home page.

However this task appears to lock up my app. This causes my app to be unable to respond to any requests for a minute or so. why? I thought the whole point of running it in a thread is so it doesn't lock up the app.

when that task is commented out the problem goes away. First of all is this the correct way of running those methods on a seperate thread in the background?
[image]

Does this screen say antyhing significant? It looks like to me it  trying to dispose everything but the thread hasn't finished yet

Does the weird icon next to "sqldatareader.close" mean anything?

```
 public class OLB : IOLB
{

    private struct SlotResult
    {
        public List<Schedule> Nurses { get; set; }

        public List<Schedule> Appointments { get; set; }

        public TimeSlotInfo2 TimeSlotInfo { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }

    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(OLB));
    private static readonly object locker = new object();

    private string sqlmartin = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MartinConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    private MARTINEntities martindb = new MARTINEntities();

    #region IDisposable

    // Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
    private bool disposed = false;

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            martindb.Dispose();
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        //
        disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion IDisposable
```

Everytime the above class uses the Idisposable interface it slows everything down significantly. When it's removed it works much much much faster.

two questions 
1)why do I need the idisposeable
2)why should it have a negative effect

Comment: We'll need to see what you do in those method calls. Otherwise, Are you doing anything with the returned `Task`?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way of deferring work to a background thread. Are you perhaps waiting the task using `Wait()` or `Result`? Those are blocking calls and may be blocking your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It a huge method with various store procedures. Therefore its not practical to post it online. Plus it's company property.

Comment: @Ageis Are you invoking a blocking call on the task, which `Wait` or `Result`?

Comment: No in the method that contains that task it actually refreshes the schedule just for the selected day then returns the results. The task is supposed to run it for 30 days incase anything has been booked using one of our other sub systems.  Because of other sub systems, this method is exposed to other systems via a webapi.

Comment: Tasks don't block the UI unless you call `Wait()` or `Result` on them from the UI thread. It's impossible to help unless you post more of the code. In the meantime, while debugging, pause your application when it locks up and check the [Parallel Stacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998398.aspx) debug window. This will show which threads are running, where each of them is and what caused blocking

Comment: Those threads are blocked talking to SQL Server. Maybe blocking, or a distributed deadlock. use sp_whoisactive to see what's running and what's blocked right now. I think there will be two sessions being blocked by lock waits.

Comment: None of these threads is the UI thread. Where is the UI thread and what is it doing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is no UI thread. This is ASP.NET.

Comment: @usr ! Just noticed from the stack. The OP talked about the app locking up. I suspect the OP mistook "takes a long time" for "locking up" - which makes the entire investigation pointless